# how to use the ssl flags with heidisql's cli arguments?

Tags: ssl, heidisql

HeidiSql supports CLI arguments: https://www.heidisql.com/help.php#commandline

I want to use the sslcacertificate option (-sslca or --sslcacertificate) but I keep getting errors, most likely because I am not using that flag correctly.

For example, let's say my current directory has a cert.pem which is the CA.

How do I use this with heidisql CLI arguments? Other args are omitted to reduce bloat.

heidisql.exe -sslca "./cert.pem"
heidisql.exe -sslca "cert.pem"
heidisql.exe -sslca="cert.pem"

Etc.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Double posted from https://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=39208 ? What about my reply there? Try to use the full path instead of "./xyz". And use the Windows backslash, not the Linux forward slash in paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `--sslcacertificate="cert.pem"` which works.

Also specifiyng the full path works: `--sslcacertificate="c:/cert.pem"`